# IIS CORS, how to add route exception

Tags: authentication, iis, cors, unauthorized

I do have two servers, server A and server B.
server A runs on IIS with windows authentication. I also do have a Slim/Twig/PHP construct on server B. 
I calling a route on server B by using ajax on server A

ajax on server A

```
function triggerBalloonNotification(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://serverB/route/on/serverB"
    })
    .done(function( json ) {
        console.log('done');
    });
}
```

this triggers an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - error which i countered by adding the following to the web.config on server B

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

now i 'only' get an 401 unauthorized error (because of the windows authentication on server B).

how do i need to config the iis on server B to exclude a specific route from the authentication?

**edit**
to be more specific: i know that i can exclude a physical folder, but i want to exclude a route which is 'not there' (in the filesystem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution.

added

```
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
```

to the ajax call on server A and set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' to 'true' on server B